# How to add a tool-bar button in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, toolbar, emacs24, dot-emacs

I try to add a button in the tool-bar but that doesn't works.
how to do that, i check in Emacs wiki and i find nothing.
I used emacs 24.3.1.
The toolsbar are displayed but not my new item.

---

I can run it with eval-buffer but not with my .emacs or find another solution to resolve that.
When i add it with eval-buffer my button leave my toolbar after a scroll.

```
(defun omar-hotel ()
 "another nonce menu function"
 (interactive)
 (message "hotel, motel, holiday inn"))

(define-key global-map [tool-bar omar-button]
'(menu-item "Hotel" omar-hotel
   :image (image :type xpm :file "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/etc/images/jump-to.xpm")
   )
)
```

Comment: Try changing `omar-hotel` to `[omar-hotel]` in your menu-item.

And perhaps ensure that `tool-bar-mode` is turned on before this code is invoked from your init file.  But trying that I see the same thing as you: it works when eval'd but not from `.emacs`.

Comment: Try changing omar-hotel to [omar-hotel] in your menu-item . that doesn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i found a simple solution to add a toolbar button "spell" is the image in /usr/share/emacs/23.4/etc/images/

```
(defun omar-hotel ()
 "another nonce menu function"
 (interactive)
 (message "hotel, motel, holiday inn"))

    (tool-bar-add-item "spell" 'omar-hotel
               'omar-hotel
               :help   "Run fonction omar-hotel")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but you need to execute it after tool bar is active.

If you add your code to your .emacs like this, your problem should be gone:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key global-map [tool-bar omar-button]
              '(menu-item "Hotel" omar-hotel
                          :image (image :type xpm :file "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/etc/images/jump-to.xpm")
                          ))))
```

Comment: I add your code in my .emacs. I check if i have something wrong after the definition of the function but nothing in rapport with tool-bar.